# va_arg error on Linux i386

Tags: c, linux, gcc, variadic-functions

I am developing a DEBUG message printing function in my Pro*C code. I am getting error on following line:

```
fmt = va_arg(args, char *);
```

The error is as follow:

```
Syntax error at line 672, column 40, file commonutil_x.pc:
Error at line 672, column 40 in file commonutil_x.pc
             fmt = va_arg(args, char * ); 
.......................................1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

   ( * & + - ~ ! ^ ++ -- ... sizeof, an identifier,
   a quoted string, a numeric constant,
The symbol "..." was substituted for ")" to continue.
```

My machine os informations are as following:

```
Linux Babo 2.6.9-89.ELsmp #1 SMP Mon Apr 20 10:34:33 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

But I wrote the same code in a small C program it get compiled and worked.
Can any one let me know why it is not working in Pro*C?
Also compiled my larger Pro*C program on a x86_64 linux machine, it get compiled without any errors. Here are the full information about second machine:

```
Linux Habo 2.6.18-128.el5 #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 11:41:38 EST 2008 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Please help me why it is working on x86_64 and not working on i386 ?

Comment: Second wild guess: Bad installation and Pro*C doesn't get the va_arg definition and thus consider it as a function instead as a macro?

Comment: Thanks AProgrammer for your reply. You mean gcc is not correctly installed or Pro*C ? As in my test c program it worked. Let me make a small test Pro*C program then I will share results with you.

Comment: what are you #include'ing to define va_arg?

Comment: Thanks Jay for your interest. I am using <stdarg.h> as the other implementation is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you've confused the 32-bit Pro*C precompiler but not the 64-bit version, you have probably hit a bug in the Pro*C precompiler.

Recommendation: move the logging function that gives an error into a separate, pure C source file, and compile that without the Pro*C compiler.

Another option, given the nature of the error messages, is to replace the `char *` with a plain type name.  It is fairly clear that the Pro*C precompiler is expecting that `*` to be a multiplication symbol rather than part of a type name.

```
typedef char *charptr;

fmt = va_arg(args, charptr);
```

This is not as good as separating the compilation, in my view.

I'm not sure whether it is feasible (and it very probably is not sensible), but you could consider running the C preprocessor over the source before submitting it to the Pro*C precompiler.  Not recommended, but it might resolve the problem.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan for your reply. I have tested the logging function in pure C source file. It get compiled and worked as well.

Comment: I tried your above recommendation. Now I got different error like this : make: *** [commonutil_x.o] Error 1

Comment: @Qumer: there's nowhere near enough information in the make error message to be able to diagnose what is wrong.  Superficially, it appears that there are still problems compiling your `commonutil_x.pc` file into an object file, even after removing the logging function.

Comment: @Jonathan thank you for your reply. But the issue is if comment the above single line, the file get compiled and object file is also generated.

Comment: @Jonathan, you are right there is one other issue. You suggestion worked.Thank you again :)

Comment: @Qumer: if you omit the line that causes trouble, yes, the code will compile.  The problem is that the missing function (macro, actually) call means the code that was compiled is also fundamentally broken; it does not initialize `args` correctly, so when you go to use it, you get into trouble - probably a crash.